# How to write a single SQL query to single out a subgroup with several conditions regarding the number of sequence of the characteristic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

[image]

I need to get this table:

[image]

One class should correspond to one id. The class is selected as follows: 1) the most common class for id is chosen (for example, id 222 corresponds to class C). 2) If the number of classes is equal (as for id 111), then a class is selected that was on the last date (for example, for id 111 classes A and B occur 3 times, but B is typed because it was the last date for this id).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do it with just one grouping subquery:

```
SELECT id, 
(SELECT TOP 1 t2.class FROM tbl t2
  WHERE t2.id=t1.id GROUP BY t2.class 
  ORDER BY COUNT(t2.class) DESC, 
           MAX(t2.date1) DESC) class
FROM tbl t1 GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to rank, then filter when the rank is 1.

```
;WITH IdRankings AS
(
    SELECT
        T.Id,
        T.Class,
        Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.ID ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC, MAX(T.date1) DESC)
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
    GROUP BY
        T.Id,
        T.Class
)
SELECT
    I.Id,
    I.Class
FROM
    IdRankings AS I
WHERE
    I.Ranking = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You an do this with no subqueries, if you like:

```
select top (1) with ties t.id, t.class
from t
group by t.id, t.class
order by row_number() over (partition by t.id order by count(*) desc, max(t.date) desc);
```

Comment: I like this approach! `top n with ties` is new to me. Since when (which SQL-Server version) has it been available?

Comment: Ahh, I found it: `with ties`was first introduced with SQL-Server 2005. Therefore it should now be available "everywhere" where you find a working SQL-Server instance.